# Angular EventEmitter vs. Communication via Service

Tags: angular

Lets assume we got a deep nested architecture with one main component and 3 layers of subcomponents. For example:

```
todo->todo list->todo list action bar->todo list button
```

There will be other components as well.

When we use EventEmitter we would have to go theough all the layers up to todo component. 
The alternative would be to have a communication service with an observable to communicate from the button component with the todo component.

What are the ups and downs to use the one way or the other? What way should I go for?

Answer (score 8):

This is a design perspective .

Generally what i have figured out is if the application size is medium to huge then go for Shared services using either `Behaviour Subject` or `Replay Subject` to transmit message to other components .

And even better design is to go for `ngrx`i:e using redux in Angular.
the only downside to this is the extra code you need to write for your actions and reducers but the plus is all the logic is separated from the components which in redux world are know as dumb components. Once done it will be a life saver using `ngrx dev tools` to track state at any moment in time, and it will be easy for you to track which event or action is fired when and how to debug and make additions to code .

Only if your app size is small i will suggest you to go with Event emitters as with multiple nested components  you are engulfed in a spaghetti code . You cannot keep track of all the firing events and then you end up re writting your code .

More on using Event Emitters vs Shared Services [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq).There is a particular question just for that.

More on ngrx [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx). This link uses ngrx v2.

I have worked on a small app using ngrx v.4 and the following is the git repo for the same [git](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores) and the working [example](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores)

Comment: What is the granularity on which you'd recommend using shared services? Services are good and all but only if they have to manage one global state which is a problem if you have multiple instances of a component.

Comment: Services are Singleton and To be used as single Source of truth The component using those Services can create copies of the data from the Service and use it without mutating it.